# Asp.Net Core Implementation Factory is not registering the Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp.net core 3.1

I am trying to inject a class using .Net core DI Implementation Factory Pattern. The Code runs fine on **local machine** but as soon as **I push the code to production** it gives me error. Even If i run the code on production as a local it gives me same error

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Core.ViewModels.Tenant.TenantEditModel' has been registered.
```

My Implementation is as follows.

**I have following injection in Startup class**

```
services.AddScoped<TenantResolver>();
services.AddScoped<TenantEditModel>(t=>t.GetService<TenantResolver>().GetTenant());
```

**The Tenant Resolver Class is**

```
public class TenantResolver
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public TenantResolver(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public TenantEditModel GetTenant()
        {
            return (TenantEditModel)_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["tenant"];
        }
}
```

**Now In my _Layout.cshtml view I inject the service in following way**

```
@inject Core.ViewModels.Tenant.TenantEditModel Tenant
@{
    string themeName = string.Empty;
    themeName = (Tenant.Theme.ToLower() == "default") ?
        $"/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" :
        $"/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.{Tenant.Theme.ToLower()}.min.css";
}
```

Why I am having error on production even If run the application locally on production? But in my localhost machine the code works fine

Comment: Seems like your GetTenant method returns null, and thus DI thinks factory has failed.

Comment: Thanks man. debugging solved the issue. Indeed GetTenant method was returning null